# Changing a numpy array in place based on values in a given column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
array([[ 0.68597575,  0.05544651, -1.        ],
       [ 0.33494648,  0.46368367,  1.        ],
       [ 0.42486765,  0.89427025,  1.        ],
       [ 0.62408611,  0.64633939,  1.        ],
       [ 0.37087957,  0.53077302, -1.        ],
       [ 0.21664159,  0.10786084, -1.        ],
       [ 0.13003626,  0.18425347, -1.        ]])
```

I want the rows having last values `-1` to be multiplied by -1 and also replaced in the actual matrix.

I tried this:

```
def transform(data):
    for row in data:
        if row[-1] == -1:
            row = row * -1
```

but I know there would be something simpler than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the for loop by doing:

```
data[data[:, -1] == -1] *= -1
```

Answer (score 1):

i prefer to do this in two steps for two reasons: (i) easier to understand the code; and (ii) often the boolean index created in the first step can be reused elsewhere in the data pipeline

create the Boolean index that selects the rows:

```
idx = M[:,-1] == -1
```

do the transform on the indexed data:

```
M[idx,] *= -1
```

Comment: yep--looks like you posted yours while i was still writing mine, which is consistent with the time diff (~ 3 minutes apart, and in those 3 min i split my answer into two lines and added some comments to make it easier to understand)